# Javascript - value from array to variable

Tags: javascript, object, scope, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I am writing a JavaScript code to create YouTube Play list for a webpage.
While writing a code I encountered a problem which I am bit aware but seems I did not understand it correctly yet.

The problem is, I am taking values from an array and passing it to init onclick event handler function. But when I click an object I don't get value I am passing to it. I get last value of an array object.

I know the solution, if I use `let` instead of `var`, I am getting expected results. 
`let plist_ids = plist[i];` instead of `var plist_ids = plist[i];`

I have two question.
How do I get correct values in this case without using LET?
If there is no easy solution, then is it okay to use LET?

```
  <body>
    <div id="plist" >
        <ul>            
        </ul>        
    </div>
```

```
    function createList() {
    var play_list = document.getElementById('plist').children[0];
    var plist = player.getPlaylist();
    var atag =[];
    var li = document.createElement("li");

        for (i=0; i<plist.length; i++) {

                var plist_ids = plist[i];  
                atag[i] = document.createElement("a");
                atag[i].innerHTML = i + "<br>";
                atag[i].href = "javascript: void(0);";

                atag[i].onclick = function () {
                                 console.log(plist_ids);
                            };

                li.appendChild(atag[i]);
                play_list.appendChild(li);
            }
    }
    player = {
        getPlaylist: function () {
            return [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
        }
    }
    createList();
</script>
```

Comment: Using let is recommended pertaining to the new ES6 standards.

Comment: Let is not supported by all browsers. Your problem is the lack of closure

Comment: Yes, JJJ, mplungjan, It is already answered. Sorry to post it again without digging it enough. Now what?

Comment: Like this: `function createList() {
  var play_list = document.querySelector('#plist>ul');
  var plist = player.getPlaylist();
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  for (var i = 0; i < plist.length; i++) {
    var plist_id = plist[i];
    atag = document.createElement("a");
    atag.innerHTML = i + "<br>";
    atag.href = "#";
    atag.setAttribute("data-playlistid",plist_id);
    atag.onclick = function() {
      console.log(this.getAttribute("data-playlistid"));
      return false;
    };
    li.appendChild(atag);
    play_list.appendChild(li);
  }
}`

Comment: It worked without any issue. I think now I got it correctly.

Comment: hi, mplungjan, Just a followup. I understand another way of resolving this problem by, js iife. ` atag[i].onclick = function (j) {
                                   return function() {  console.log(j)};
                                }(plist_ids);`